# After form submit redirect on PDF with new tab in gravity from

Tags: wordpress

I am using multiple gravity forms.

I have set the link in the confirmation section in the gravity form setup.

It is redirecting on the given PDF, But I want to open that redirected PDF on another tab.

It is working for the single form but I want to use this for the multiple gravity forms.

I had already tried the hook below :

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation', 'custom_confirmation', 10, 4 );
```

For the particular form I had tried with form ID :

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_6', 'custom_confirmation', 10, 4 );
```

Can you please help me to overcome this issue ??

Answer (score 2):

The documentation page about this filter 'gform_confirmation' provides different situation examples for using it correctly.

To open the confirmation URL in a new tab/window, you need to add an inline javascript with the target *_blank* , as Pradeep mentioned.

[Gravity Forms - gform_confirmation doc](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation/) ***(Check #4 - Open the page or redirect in a new tab)***

```
add_filter('gform_confirmation', 'custom_confirmation', 10, 4);
function custom_confirmation($confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax) {
    GFCommon::log_debug('gform_confirmation: running.');

    $forms = array(3, 6, 7); // Target forms with id 3, 6 and 7. Change this to fit your needs.
    if (!in_array($form['id'], $forms) || empty($confirmation['redirect'])) {
         return $confirmation;
    }
                
    $url = esc_url_raw($confirmation['redirect']);
                
    GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . '(): Redirect to URL: ' . $url);
                
    $confirmation = 'Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.';
    $confirmation .= GFCommon::get_inline_script_tag("window.open('$url', '_blank');");
      return $confirmation;
};
```

**OR if you prefer to use it on all or specific Forms:**

```
add_filter('gform_confirmation', 'custom_confirmation', 10, 4);
add_filter('gform_confirmation_4', 'custom_confirmation', 10, 4);
function custom_confirmation($confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax) {
    GFCommon::log_debug('gform_confirmation: running.');

    $url = esc_url_raw($confirmation['redirect']);
    GFCommon::log_debug(__METHOD__ . '(): Redirect to URL: ' . $url);
    $confirmation = 'Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.';
    $confirmation .= GFCommon::get_inline_script_tag("window.open('$url', '_blank');");

    return $confirmation;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem is pretty simple, I think you forgot to give "target='_blank'" in your path to the pdf.